# Multiple SQL Queries with Google Script and JDBC connectors in a single Sheet

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm using an App Script with JDBC connector to create a connection with my MySQL stats database.
I would like to be able to run multiple Queries in a single script to pull out specific info from my database into a single sheet
All my Queries' results have the same structure (all are group by date) YEAR,MONTH,DAY,VALUE and I was wondering if it was possible to have the YEAR,MONTH, DATE Columns fixed and all the other results populating following columns in my results.

Something like
Col A: YEAR, Col B: MONTH, Col C: DAY, Col D: Result from Query 1, Col E: Result from Query 2....

Here is what I started with

```
function loadData() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address;
var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

var stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.setMaxRows(10);
var results = stmt.executeQuery('Select YEAR(dateCreated) as yearAdded,MONTH(dateCreated) as monthAdded, DAY(dateCreated) as dayAdded,sum(amount)/100 from stripeTransactions GROUP BY yearAdded ,monthAdded,dayAdded;');
var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); 
while (results.next()) {
  var rowArray = new Array();
   for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
    rowArray.push(results.getString(col+1));
  }
  sheet.appendRow(rowArray);
}

results.close();
stmt.close();
var stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
stmt2.setMaxRows(10);
var results2= stmt2.executeQuery('Select YEAR(dateAdded) as yearAdded,MONTH(dateAdded) as monthAdded, DAY(dateAdded) as dayAdded,sum(amount) from itunestransactions GROUP BY yearAdded ,monthAdded,dayAdded;');
var numCols2 = results2.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
 while (results2.next()) {
  var rowArray2 = new Array();
   for (var cal = numCols; cal < numCols2; cal++) {
    rowArray2.push(results2.getString(cal+1));
  }
 sheet.appendRow(rowArray2);
}

results2.close();
stmt2.close();
}
```

Thanks
(this script only append rows for every results, I guess could have a single sheet per results for each query then merge every sheet in one but I'd rather do it in a single sheet from the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know more advanced MySQL to pull this off but you can nest sub-queries into your main query.

Moreover, if you want your queries to be more efficient you can wrap your queries into a MySQL stored procedure and then call that procedure from Apps Script via JDBC.

Here are links to some tutorials to get you started:

[MySQL Subquery](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/)

[MySQL Stored Procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx)