# How can I keep my connection alive for multiple queries using JDBC and Google-App-Script?

Tags: html, mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729885/multiple-sql-queries-with-google-script-and-jdbc-connectors-in-a-single-sheet) but it didn't really helped me solving my problem.

I use a `HTML` dialog box opened with an add-on on google spreadsheets and I'm using `JBDC`.

I load from multiple queries some datas from my `MYSQL` database, I also have a search bar to search for datas in the DB and in the future I would like my HTML to automatically show various database values depending on option choosen in my `HTML`page. Basically that's a lot of queries for only one App so I guess there should be one connection object to use.

I've tried multiple things that I can show you in pseudo-code.

1. open a new connection every time

so here would be my **GS** file

```
function firstFunc()
{
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  //do my thing
  return (datas);
}
function secondFunc()
{
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  //do my thing
  return (datas);
}
function thirdFunc()
{
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  //do my thing
  return (datas);
}
```

and then my `HTML`

```
<script>
     var onSuccessFirst = function (data){
      //update my HTML with data
     }
     var onSuccessSecond = function (data){
      //update my HTML with data
     }
     var onSuccessThird = function (data){
      //update my HTML with data
     }
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessFirst).firstFunc();
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessSecond).secondFunc();
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessThird).thirdFunc();
</script>
```

But as I'm using a free database provider for developping the third connection returns me an error telling me to verify password or username because it failed to connect to database.

2. try passing the connection from the server to the client then back to the server:

**GS file**

```
function getConnection()
{
  return (Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd););
}
function firstFunc(conn)
{
  conn...
  //do my thing
  return (datas);
}
function secondFunc(conn)
{
  conn...
  //do my thing
  return (datas);
}
function thirdFunc(conn)
{
  conn...
  //do my thing
  return (datas);
}
```

and then my `HTML`

```
<script>
     var onSuccessFirst = function (data){
      //update my HTML with data
     }
     var onSuccessSecond = function (data){
      //update my HTML with data
     }
     var onSuccessThird = function (data){
      //update my HTML with data
     }
     var onSuccessConnection = function(conn)
     {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessFirst).firstFunc(conn);
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessSecond).secondFunc(conn);
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessThird).thirdFunc(conn);
     }
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessConnection).getConnection();
</script>
```

But here `conn` is `null`.

I also have a lot of queries sent when my input (search bar) is `onchange` and I use first method it works except it doesn't allow quick typing as it increases connection requests on each character typed.

What can I do?

Comment: `But as I'm using a free database provider for developping the third connection returns me an error.`what was the error?

Comment: @I'-'I I've just edited my post. The error message is not in english so didn't put it but this has nothing to do with passwords or username as it works when I reduce my connection to two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Try chaining with your first approach:

```
<script>
 var onSuccessThird = function (data){
  //update my HTML with data
 }
 var onSuccessSecond = function (data){
  //update my HTML with data
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessThird).thirdFunc();
 }
 var onSuccessFirst = function (data){
  //update my HTML with data
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessSecond).secondFunc();
 }
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessFirst).firstFunc();
</script>
```

#### Notes:

- `google.script.run` is a async function. All three runs will be called one by one without waiting for the the previous run to finish, which means almost 3 Jdbc connections will be  opened more or less at the same time in the first approach.
- A single `script.run` call will close the connection. So in your second approach, the `conn` will be null when the first run is over or before that.

  > JDBC connections close automatically when a script finishes executing. (Keep in mind that a single google.script.run call counts as a complete execution, even if the HTML service page that made the call remains open.)

#### References:

- [Closing connections](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#closing_connections)

Comment: Thank you this worked. Only wondering if there was a better approach but I'll keep this one. I will probably use `join` query in the future.

Comment: @JSmith Glad it worked. If you found a better way now or in the future, feel free to post it for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use connection pooling, 
else you can keep the connection alive for one complete set of transactions by checking null and opening / closing the connection only once for a full set of request response.

Comment: @usr_ng do you have any example code of connection pooling using `jdbc` and `google-app-script`?

Comment: This being a specific case, as the google app script is unable to retain the connection and as per their document to check the connection it is like creating a new connection so you would have to go with the second approach, that you do all the activity in one go. I think the pool solution is not a solution. My Bad.

Comment: I'll try waiting for another answer and mark yours as correct if I don't get any better. Could you update your post and explain what you've told me in the comment, plus if you have links that document this kind of behaviour this woul be nice. Thanks in advance.